# Does Xcode require El Capitan to run?

Tags: macos, xcode, system-requirements

I am planning to buy a Mac Mini and would like to know the minimum requirements to run Xcode 7.

I didn't find clear information on this topic.

Comment: Or if you want to run an older version of Xcode on an older version of OS X you could download Xcode 6 from Apple Developer Downloads (if you are a registered Apple developer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html), in the Apple Developers webpage:

> Xcode 7 requires a Mac running OS X version 10.10.4 or later. It
>   includes SDKs for watchOS 2.0, iOS 9, and OS X version 10.11.

As you see in the attached pic, Yosemite can still be valid to run XCode7, if it is updated to the 10.10.4+ version required.
[image]

Comment: So, the answer would be yes? Or would Yosemite suffice?

Comment: Yes, if Yosemite is updated to at least version 10.10.4+. To check this, press the Mela button > About this Mac, and you'll see your current OSX version.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think that this would change in the near future?

Comment: You mean allowing older OSX versions to install XCode7?

Comment: I am looking to buy a Mac Mini for iPhone app testing. But I wonder if maybe I would buy one that supports Yosemite, it might not support El Capitan and maybe I would not be able to use it in the near future, if this requirements increases. But I'm very new to Apple

Comment: If you buy a Mac mini (Late 2014), its later OS X included is 10.10.2, but you can easily update to El Capitan, since it supports all Mac mini version from 2009.

Comment: Macs bought from the Apple Store come with El Capitan pre-installed

Comment: @Z0q Every Mac that can run Yosemite can run El Capitan.

Comment: Perfect. I would like to cast some upvotes, but I do not have enough reputation :)